# (sas) concatenate multiple files from different folders

Tags: merge, sas, concatenation, xls, directory

I'm a relatively new SAS user, so please bear with me!

I have 63 folders that each contain a uniquely named xls file, all containing the same variables in the same order. I need to concatenate them into a single file. I would post some of the code I've tried but, trust me, it's all gone horribly awry and is totally useless. Below is the basic library structure in a libname statement, though:

```
    `libname JC 'W:\JCs\JC Analyses 2016-2017\JC Data 2016-2017\2 - Received from JCs\&jcname.\2016_&jcname..xls`
```

(there are 63 unique &jcname values)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your question does not meet SO guidelines, please show what you've tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have the code working (or attempted) for importing one excel file?  If so, show that. Have you attempted a macro that would take &jcname as a parameter and read in one excel file? If so, show that. Once you have that, it shouldn't be that much more to make the macro loop over a list of 63 names. Showing your code will help others help you.

Comment: While I agree with the comments above, and even though this is a broad question, I'd argue that an answer is still useful.  There don't seem to be any good answers on this site, and the search results for similar problems turn up some sketchy answers.  This isn't a day-today problem in SAS, and even the basic approach will be unfamiliar to beginning SAS programmers.  It still makes me stop and think.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common requirement, but it requires a fairly uncommon knowledge of multiple SAS functions to execute well.

I like to approach this problem with a two step solution:

1. Get a list of filenames
2. Process each filename in a  loop

While you can process each filename as you read it, it's a lot easier to debug and maintain code that separates these steps.

**Step 1: Read filenames**

I think the best way to get a list of filenames is to use `dread()` to read 
directory entries into a dataset as follows:

```
filename myfiles 'c:\myfolder';

data filenames (keep=filename);
    dir = dopen('myfiles'); 
    do file = 1 to dnum(dir);
        filename = dread(dir,file); 
        output;
    end;
    rc = dclose(dir);
run;
```

After this step you can verify that the correct filenames have been read be printing the dataset.  You could also modify the code to only output certain types of files.  I leave this as an exercise for the reader.

**Step 2: use the files**

Given a list of names in a dataset, I prefer to use `call execute()` inside a data step to process each file.

```
data _null_;
 set filenames;
 call execute('%import('||filename||')');
run;
```

I haven't included a macro to read in the Excel files and concatenate the dataset (partly because I don't have a suitable list of Excel files to test, but also because it's a situational problem).  The stub macro below just outputs the filenames to the log, to verify that it's running:

```
%macro import(filename);
    /* This is a dummy macro.  Here is where you would do something with the file */
    %put &filename;
%mend;
```

**Notes:**

Arguably there are many are many examples of how to do this in multiple places on the web, e.g.:

- this SAS knowledge base article (http://support.sas.com/kb/41/880.html)
- or [this paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/057-29.pdf) from SUGI,

However, most of them rely on the use of `pipe` to run a `dir` or `ls` command, which I feel is the wrong approach because it's platform dependent and in many modern environments the ability to pipe shell commands will be disabled.

I based this on an answer by Daniel Santos in [communities.sas.com](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Read-in-multiple-excel-text-files/td-p/15244), but, given the superior functionality of stackoverflow I'd much rather see a good answer here.

Comment: Example 1 & 2 from the macro documentation should be enough. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/SAS-9-4-Macro-Language-Reference-Has-a-New-Appendix/ta-p/291716